# React - useReducer with asynchronous CRUD operations

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api, use-reducer

I am trying to figure out how to use `useReducer` with asynchronous CRUD operations (using the fetch API).

In my mind the reducer function would look like this:

```
async function reducer(action, state) {
    const newState = {...state};

    switch (action.type) {
        case types.ADD_ITEM:
            try {
                const {item} = await addItem(action.payload.item);
                newState.items.push(item);
            }
            catch (e) {
                newState.error = e.message;
            }
            break;
        case types.REMOVE_ITEM:
            try {
                await removeItem(action.payload.itemId);
                newState.items = newState.items.filter(value.id !== action.payload);
            }
            catch (e) {
                newState.error = e.message;
            }
            break;
        case types.EDIT_ITEM:
            try {
                const {item} = await editItem(action.payload.itemId, action.payload.item);
                newState.items[newState.items.findIndex(value => value.id === action.payload.itemId)] = item;
            }
            catch (e) {
                newState.error = e.message;
            }
            break;
    }

    return newState;
}
```

These would be the fetch functions:

```
async function addItem(item) {
    const response = await fetch('addItemRoute', {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            item
        })
    });
    return response.json();
}

async function removeItem(itemId) {
    const response = await fetch('removeItemRoute/' + itemId, {
        method: "DELETE"
    });
    return response.json();
}

async function editItem(itemId, item) {
    const response = await fetch('editItemRoute/'+ itemId, {
        method: "PUT",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            item
        })
    });
    return response.json();
}
```

But the reducer function cannot be an async function.

What would be the standard way to handle concepts like this?

Any help/reference is truly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I think you misunderstood the role of reducer. In React world, there is a thing call global state (a way to pass values down to children without having to pass as props), which traditionally being handled by another package called Redux. The `reducer` only handle taking whatever you `dispatch`, decide what action to take to update the global state based on the type of `action` which is not asynchronous. The `action` is what you use to decide what to `dispatch` and also the way for you to get the data to dispatch so usually all the HTTP calls occurs here. Since `useReducer` will returns for you the current state and the `dispatch` function as well, you can basically pass this `dispatch` to your `action`. You can take a look at my example below based on your example for clearer image of what you might want to do:

You may want to put all your action in a action file called `action.js` like this:

```js
async function addItem(item, dispatch) {
    const response = await fetch('addItemRoute', {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            item
        })
    });
    return dispatch({
      type: "ADD_ITEM",
      payload: response.json()});
}

async function removeItem(itemId, dispatch) {
    const response = await fetch('removeItemRoute/' + itemId, {
        method: "DELETE"
    });
    return dispatch({
      type: "ADD_ITEM",
      payload: response.json()
     });
}

async function editItem(itemId, item, dispatch) {
    const response = await fetch('editItemRoute/'+ itemId, {
        method: "PUT",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            item
        })
    });
    return dispatch({
      type: "ADD_ITEM",
      payload: response.json()
     });
}
```

Then in your reducer, you can do the regular without having to call the `fetch` or `async` calls like this:

```js
async function reducer(action, state) {
    const newState = {...state};

    switch (action.type) {
        case types.ADD_ITEM:
            try {
                const {item} = action.payload;
                newState.items.push(item);
            }
            catch (e) {
                newState.error = e.message;
            }
            break;
        case types.REMOVE_ITEM:
            try {
                newState.items = newState.items.filter(value.id !== action.payload);
            }
            catch (e) {
                newState.error = e.message;
            }
            break;
        case types.EDIT_ITEM:
            try {
                const {item} = action.payload;
                newState.items[newState.items.findIndex(value => value.id === action.payload.itemId)] = item;
            }
            catch (e) {
                newState.error = e.message;
            }
            break;
    }

    return newState;
}
```

Then in your component with the button that you want to execute this, you can do something like this:

```js
const MyComponent = ()=> {
  ...
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  ...
  return (
    ...
    <button onClick={addItem(item, dispatch)}/>
    ...
}
```

You can reference the core concept of redux [here](https://redux.js.org/introduction/core-concepts) which IMO explains very clearly the functionality of reducer, dispatch, actions and global state. If you want you can also tried out Redux as well, here's their [tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/quick-start).